# How could you convert the following recursion function in graphs using networkx with dynamic programming?

Tags: python, recursion, networkx, dynamic-programming

I am trying to convert the following recursive function to one with dynamic programming

```
def u_rec(y,arrexp,t_max,r,B,t=0):
  if y==0:
    return 0, t_max-t, arrexp
  if t>=t_max:
    return float('inf'), t_max-t, arrexp
  else:
    if p_generalizada(arrexp, y, r, B)==1:
      dds=[]
      if list(random_digraph.predecessors(y))==[]:
          return 0,t_max-t, arrexp 
      else:
        for d in list(random_digraph.predecessors(y)):
          ddsa=u_rec(d, arrexp,t_max,r,B)[0]+ random_digraph[d][y]['weight']
          dds.append(ddsa)
        argmin=np.argmin(dds)
        arrexp= e_truncada_generalizada(arrexp, list(random_digraph.predecessors(y))[argmin], r)
      return dds[argmin], t_max-t, arrexp
    else:
      t=t+1
      distop=0
      for p in P_x(random_digraph, y, B, arrexp):
        distop+= u_rec(p,arrexp, t_max, r,B)[0]+ random_digraph[p][y]['weight']
      return distop, t_max-t, e_truncada_generalizada(arrexp, y, r)
```

Where n is given and the other functions I'm using are:

```
#Function that stores the experience of the nodes, the cap ensures that we no longer store more information 
def e_truncada_generalizada(arrexp,node, r):
  tope = np.max(r)
  if arrexp[node]<tope:
    arrexp[node]=arrexp[node]+1
  return arrexp


#function to check xp
def checkxp_generalizada(arrexp,node):
  return arrexp[node]


#"probability" function
def p_generalizada(arrexp,node, r, B):
    if node in B:
      for parent in list(random_digraph.predecessors(node)):
        if checkxp_generalizada(arrexp, parent) < r[parent]:
          return 0
      return 1
    else:
      return 1

def P_x(random_digraph,x, B, arrexp):
  if x not in B:
    return []
  else:
    p_x=[]
    for d in list(random_digraph.predecessors(x)):
      if checkxp_generalizada(arrexp, d)<r[d]:
        p_x.append(d)
    return p_x


B=[2, n-1]
```

random_digraph is generated using nx.DiGraph() and adding n-1 nodes with random weights and edges to finally add node n that is only connected to node n-1

Checking again, I have a problem with the u_rep function itself, the function always returns 0 in the tmax-t part
any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Basically the u_rec function, calculates the optimal distance between a node y and node 0, I'm new to dynamic programming, so I don't know how to start, for the part of the problem with tmax-t I tried to change the function so that it only receives a parameter t y every time the function enters the case p(y)=0
then t=t-1, but when executing it always returned the original t parameter.